# How to reset tremolo?

Tags: electric-guitar, tremolo-system

Every time I have to replace strings on my electric guitar (whether it's because the string broke or just because they're starting to sound bad), my tremolo action always sinks really low into the cavity. A few years ago I found an effective way to fix this, but I've forgotten the method and cannot find the article I read.

question: How can I raise the tremolo action back up again? The end closest to the pickups is at normal height, but the other end is sunken way down into the cavity.

my guitar: Ibanez RG Prestige (I do not know which model exactly) with an Edge-Pro tremolo system

Comment: Sounds like you might need to adjust the springs that counter the string tension. Never used an Edge-Pro though so I don't have any specific information. Floyd Rose should be similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yrAckQ4HvE

Comment: If you use the same gauge of strings, the tension will bring the trem back up to roughly where it was. Don't worry about it dropping into the body when the strings are off - that's fine. It will come back up once you tighten the strings.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Ibanez technical forum](http://forum.ibanez.com/yaf_postst80528_Useful-Diagrams.aspx):

[image: If the tremolo is not level with the body, and the rear edge is lower than the front...]

[image: ...loosen the screws on the spring claw to reduce tension...]

[image: ...and return to the correct alignment]

The tremolo is held in position by two opposing tensions - from the strings, and from the springs in the rear cavity. You can adjust the position of the spring claw, by loosening and tightening the highlighted screws, to get the correct balance.